# Apache Spark: Driver (instead of just the Executors) tries to connect to Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I guess I'm not yet fully understanding how Spark works.

Here is my setup:

I'm running a Spark cluster in Standalone mode. I'm using 4 machines for this: One is the Master, the other three are Workers.

I have written an application that reads data from a Cassandra cluster (see https://github.com/journeymonitor/analyze/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/SparkApp.scala#L118).

The 3-nodes Cassandra cluster runs on the same machines that also host the Spark Worker nodes. The Spark Master node does not run a Cassandra node:

```
Machine 1      Machine 2        Machine 3        Machine 4
Spark Master   Spark Worker     Spark Worker     Spark Worker
               Cassandra node   Cassandra node   Cassandra node
```

The reasoning behind this is that I want to optimize data locality - when running my Spark app on the cluster, each Worker only needs to talk to its local Cassandra node.

Now, when submitting my Spark app to the cluster by running `spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master spark://machine-1` from Machine 1 (the Spark Master), I expect the following:

- a Driver instance is started on the Spark Master
- the Driver starts one Executor on each Spark Worker
- the Driver distributes my application to each Executor
- my application runs on each Executor, and from there, talks to Cassandra via `127.0.0.1:9042`

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Instead, the Spark Master tries to talk to Cassandra (and fails, because there is no Cassandra node on the Machine 1 host).

What is it that I misunderstand? Does it work differently? Does in fact the Driver read the data from Cassandra, and distribute the data to the Executors? But then I could never read data larger than `memory of Machine 1`, even if the total memory of my cluster is sufficient.

Or, does the Driver talk to Cassandra not to read data, but to find out how to partition the data, and instructs the Executors to read "their" part of the data?

If someone can enlight me, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Driver program is responsible for creating SparkContext, SQLContext and scheduling tasks on the worker nodes. It includes creating logical and physical plans and applying optimizations. To be able to do that it has to have access to the data source schema and possible other informations like schema or different statistics. Implementation details vary from source to source but generally speaking it means that data should be accessible on all nodes including application master.

At the end of the day your expectations are almost correct. Chunks of the data are fetched individually on each worker without going through driver program, but driver has to be able to connect to Cassandra to fetch required metadata.

Comment: In this case it is the Metadata about the token range and how it is divided between nodes +1