# Is joinWithCassandraTable() lazy?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I`m using Spark 1.2.1 with [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) :

```
//join with cassandra
val rdd = some_array.map(x => SomeClass(x._1,x._2)).joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, some_table)
println(timer, "Join")

//get only the jsons and create rdd temp table
val jsons = rdd.map(_._2.getString("this"))
val jsonSchemaRDD = sqlContext.jsonRDD(jsons)
jsonSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("this_json")
println(timer, "Map")
```

The output is:

```
Timer "Join"- 558 ms
Timer "Map"- 290284 ms
```

I guess the "joinWithCassandraTable()" function is lazy, if so, what is fire it up?

Comment: That's a really old version of Spark!

Comment: yes, I need to upgrade the dse version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the part which will trigger an evaluation here is `sqlContext.jsonRDD`. Since you don't provide the `schema` it has to materialize `jsons` to be able to infer it.

`joinWithCassandraTable` is is kind of similar since it has to connect to the Cassandra and fetch required metadata. See [Apache Spark: Driver (instead of just the Executors) tries to connect to Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33897586/1560062)